# Why the slow session->Run(..) on JNI in Tensorflow?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, tensorflow

I managed to use the tensorflow/examples/android demo on a java based server app using JNI. Currently i'm using it to classify a series of images and getting slow results around 15-20 seconds per JNI call. Is there any way to speed up the session-run(..) call ?

```
// On the .cc code
classifyImage(...) {
      ....
      // Create input tensor
      tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(
                             tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
                             tensorflow::TensorShape({
                                1, height, width, depth}));

     auto input_tensor_mapped = input_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();

     .......
     for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
           const float* source_row = source_data + (y * width * depth);
           for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                const float* source_pixel = source_row + (x * depth);
                for (int c = 0; c < depth; ++c) {
                      const float* source_value = source_pixel + c;
                        input_tensor_mapped(0, y, x, c) = *source_value;
                }
           }
      }
     start_time = CurrentThreadTimeUs();
     s = session->Run(input_tensors, output_names, {}, &output_tensors);
     end_time = CurrentThreadTimeUs();
}


// on the java code
     for (List<IIOImage> image : imageLists) {
            for(IIOImage index: image) {
                List<IClassifier.Recognition> results = ic.classifyImage(index);

                System.out.println("results "+ results.size());
                for (IClassifier.Recognition resultr : results) {
                 System.out.println("Result: " + resultr.getTitle());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell us which model you're using? Is it the default Inception file that comes with the Android example?

Comment: @PeteWarden im using a custom .pb from the flowers tutorial that i retrained using 5 classes of images. It is about 87mb.

Comment: are you using the GPU or the CPU? It could explain why it is so slow

Comment: @jorgemf Can you use the GPU for the inference ? Currently the code is CPU bound. I'll see if it will work better on the GPU

Comment: @mrBean That is the whole point of TF, to use the GPU. That is why your code is slow. Check the code of the graph, that you are using the GPU there and also install the TF version which supports GPU.

Comment: trying this one out with bazel build -c opt --config=cuda but currently running into some problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673305/bazel-errors-on-creating-so-file-with-tensorflow-and-cuda

Comment: @jorgemf confirming this got a good 28ms on the GPU