# Bazel Errors on creating .so file with tensorflow and cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, java-native-interface, tensorflow

Im able to create a .so file with tensorflow / bazel but without cuda. If i try bazel build -c opts --config=cuda :lib.so i get an undefined reference to main(..). Would there be a way to get rid of the errors referring to main (...) ?

Here is my BUILD file

```
cc_binary(
    name = "lib.so",
    srcs = [
        "lib.cc",
        "jni.h",
        "jni_md.h",
        "lib.h",
        "jni_utils.h", "jni_utils.cc"

    ],
    copts = tf_copts(),

     linkopts = ["-shared"],


    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
        "//tensorflow/core:framework",
        "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "//tensorflow/core:all_kernels",
        "@opencv//:opencv"
    ],
)
```

**Im getting these errors:**

failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command 
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Im getting these errors crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you just need to set linkshared = 1 onto the BUILD

```
 cc_binary(
    name = "lib.so",
    srcs = [
        "lib.cc",
        "jni.h",
        "jni_md.h",
        "lib.h",
        "jni_utils.h", "jni_utils.cc"

    ],
    copts = tf_copts(),

     linkshared = 1,


    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
        "//tensorflow/core:framework",
        "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "//tensorflow/core:all_kernels",
        "@opencv//:opencv"
    ],
)
```